# Can "Redeem Code" be directly launched from code?

Tags: android

Per google's documentation (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo#redeem), the user has to go through the purchase flow and choose "redeem code".

Is there a way to directly launch the code redemption flow that I'm not finding?

Thank you all in advance!